# How to prove that a symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a symmetric matrix whose diagonals are positive. I need to prove that this matrix is positive semidefinite.

The matrix is made up of a bunch of constants and I tried getting the eigenvalues using Maple and it was a mess.  I also tried doing something I found online [How to check if a symmetric $4\times4$ matrix is positive semi-definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40849/how-to-check-if-a-symmetric-4-times4-matrix-is-positive-semi-definite).  I tried doing Robert Israel's answer and it ended up being a mess.  Is there an easier way to prove positive semidefinite?

Comment: How large is your matrix? Perhaps you can post it here. I would venture to guess that you may be able to apply the Gershgorin Circle Theorem. This is noted in Calle's answer in the question you linked to.

Comment: Symmetric matrices with positive diagonals aren't always positive.  (E.g., $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$.)  What is your matrix?

Comment: If your matrix is not too large, see this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40849/how-to-check-if-a-symmetric-4-times4-matrix-is-positive-semi-definite

Comment: @b555: That is the question user972276 links to above.

Comment: oops my bad, sry .. had read the q i linked just a few days abck and couldnt read this q fully >.<

Comment: @EuYu ah yes, the Gershgorin Circle Theorem works!  I did not see that answer :-/ or else I would of used that.  That theorem checks out on my matrix.

Comment: Glad I could help. I will post my comment as an answer so that this doesn't go unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large is your matrix? Perhaps you can post it here. I would venture to guess that you may be able to apply the Gershgorin Circle Theorem. This is noted in Calle's answer in the question you linked to.