# Does the matrix square root have directional derivatives at semipositive points?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

$\newcommand{\psym}{\operatorname{P}_{\ge 0}}$

Let $\psym$ be the set of symmetric positive semidefinite (real) matrices.

Let $\sqrt \cdot :\psym  \to \psym $ be the unique positive semidefinite square root.

Let $A \in \psym$ be a matrix **on the boundary**, i.e $\det A=0$. Let $B$ be a *symmetric* matrix such that $A+tB$ is positive semidefinite for $t>0$ small enough**.

**Quesion:** Characterize all such pairs $A,B$ where the one sided directional derivative

$$  (d\sqrt{\cdot})_A(B)=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}  \sqrt{A+tB}:=\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{ \sqrt{A+tB}-\sqrt{A}}{t} \, \, \text{ exist.}$$

---

**Partial results:**

(1) For $A=0$ the limit exists only for $B=0$.

(2) For every $A=B$ the limit exists (and equals $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{A}$).

(3) For every $A$, there are a "lot" of matrices $B$ for which the limit does not exist (see the answer of loup blanc):

By orthogonal diagonalization, after noting that

$(d\sqrt{\cdot})_A(B)$ exists $\iff (d\sqrt{\cdot})_{V^TAV}(V^TBV)$ exists for every $V \in O_n$,

we reduce to the case $A=diag(0,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ where $a_i\geq 0$: 
For every matrix $B$ of the form $B=diag(\lambda,C)$ where $\lambda > 0,C\in M_{n-1}$ is symmetric s.t. $diag(a_2,\cdots,a_n)+C\geq 0$, 
$(d\sqrt{\cdot})_A(B)$ does not exist.

---

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770374/the-matrix-square-root-is-not-differentiable-on-the-boundary-of-the-manifold-of), it is shown that $\sqrt{\cdot} $ is not differentiable in the standard sense. In fact, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1771444/104576) shows $\psym$ is not a manifold (with boundary) at all, so "standard differentiability" does not really make sense here.

---

**
Actually, as noted by loup blanc, if $B$ is a symmetric matrix such that $A+B \in \psym$, then $A+tB \in \psym$ for small enough $t$. Indeed,

$A,A+B \in \psym$ and $\psym$ is convex, hence $(1-t)A+t(A+B)=A+tB \in \psym$.

Note that the reverse implication is false in general; It can happen that $A+tB \in \psym$, but $A+B \notin \psym$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887464/atb-ge-0-for-small-t-rightarrow-ab-ge-0#).

Answer (score 4):

** is true because $P_{\geq 0}$ is convex (as the closure of a convex).

Now, if $A$ is in the boundary, then, up to an orthonormal change of basis, $A=diag(0,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ where $a_i\geq 0$. For non-differentiability, it suffices to choose $B=diag(1,C)$ where $C\in M_{n-1}$ is symmetric s.t. $diag(a_2,\cdots,a_n)+C\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I see I wasn't completely clear. What I was really interested in is a characterization of all the pairs $A,B$ such that the directional derivative $(d\sqrt{\cdot})_A(B)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really answer, but rather a long comment:$\newcommand{\psym}{\operatorname{P}_{\ge 0}}$

When:

(1) $B$ is invertible

(2) $A,B$ commute

(3) $B^{-1}A \in \psym$

it is possible to reduce the problem to the case of $B=I$:

$$ \sqrt{A+tB}-\sqrt{A}=\sqrt{B(B^{-1}A+tI)} -\sqrt{BB^{-1}A} \stackrel{(*)}{=} \sqrt{B}\sqrt{B^{-1}A+tI}-\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B^{-1}A}=$$

$$ \sqrt{B} \cdot (\sqrt{B^{-1}A+tI}-\sqrt{B^{-1}A}) $$

where equality (*) comes from lemma 2 below. Note that $\sqrt{B^{-1}A+tI},\sqrt{B^{-1}A}$ are well defined by assumption (3).

To conclude, $$ (d\sqrt{\cdot})_A(B)=\sqrt{B}\cdot (d\sqrt{\cdot})_{B^{-1}A}(I)$$

when this equality is interpreted in the sense that the left hand exists $\iff$ the  right hand exists, and in that case they are equal.

---

**Lemma(1):**

Let $A,B \in \psym$ be commuting matrices. Then $\sqrt{A},\sqrt{B}$ commute.

**Proof:**

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134190/104576).

**Lemma(2):**

Let $A,B \in \psym$ be commuting matrices. Then $\sqrt{AB}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$.

**Proof:**

By lemma(1) $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$ is symmetric. In fact $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B} \in \psym$ (since the product is symmetric, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/483930/104576)), and its square is $AB$:

$$(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B})^2=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B} =AB$$ (where the last equality is by lemma(1))

Finally, by the uniqueness of the symmetric semipositive square root, we get $$\sqrt{AB}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B} $$.