# Matrix derivative of square root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let A be an $n\times n$  matrix  (real valued), and set $S := \sqrt{A^t A}$. What is the matrix derivative of $S$ w.r.t. $A$? I.e., what is $\frac{\partial S}{\partial A}$?

(In case of invertibility issues, I might for the time being assume that $A^t A$ is positive definite, although for the applications I have in mind I might have only positive semi-definiteness).

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the motivation you have in mind? What was your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884536/does-the-matrix-square-root-have-directional-derivatives-at-semipositive-points and references therein

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the [vec operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) for matrices, then you could proceed as follows.
$$\eqalign{
&S\,S 
  &= A^TA \cr
&S\,dS\,(I)+(I)\,dS\,S
  &= A^T\,dA\,(I)+(I)\,dA^T\,A \cr
&(I^T\otimes S+S^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dS)
  &= (I^T\otimes A^T)\,{\rm vec}(dA)+(A^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dA^T) \cr
&\Big(I\otimes S+S\otimes I\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dS)
  &= \Big((I\otimes A^T)+(A^T\otimes I)K\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dA) \cr
&\frac{\partial{\,\rm vec}(S)}{\partial{\,\rm vec}(A)}
  &= \Big(I\otimes S+S\otimes I\Big)^+
\Big((I\otimes A^T)+(A^T\otimes I)K\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
where $M^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M$, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product. The solution also takes advantage of the fact that $I$ and $S$ are symmetric.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: Why can you get away with just needing a pseudoinverse instead of an inverse in the last line? Usually I think of the pseudoinverse when finding $b$ such that $Xb\approx Y$ and then $\hat{b}=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$. But that's not going to make $Xb$ EQUAL to $Y$ unless $X$ were invertible.

Comment: @Glassjawed Your objection is certainly valid. 
Every possible solution of the linear differential relationship 
$$B\,dy = A\,dx$$
can be written using an arbitrary $p$-vector and the pseudoinverse 
$$dy = B^+A\,dx + (I-B^+B)\,p$$
The $p$-term is completely independent of the $x$-vector,
so to the extent that $\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)$
exists at all, it is given by the matrix coefficient of the $dx$-term.

Comment: That's really neat. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recall that you can perform a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) on $A$ such that:

$$A = QS$$

where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $S$ is defined uniquely as precisely what you describe above when it exists. Hence, what you really want to calculate is:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial [Q^{-1}A]}{\partial A} = Q^{-1}\otimes\mathbf{I}$$

Note the result is a fourth-order linear transformation, since we are the describing the rate of change of a second-order object $S$ with respect to another second-order linear transformation $A$.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem @user2019! If you find either my answer or greg’s to be correct/sufficient, remember to check it off/upvote it.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures Hey, how did you get = kronecker product of Q inverse and Identity. Is there some underlying method of taking derivative of matrix w.r.t. a matrix that you are using? can you please provide a reference for this rule/method? thank you

Comment: @user35687 It's actually a tensor product here (of which the Kronecker product is a flattened representation). Depending on convention, you have the rule $\frac{∂AXB^⊤}{X}= A⊗B$ or $\frac{∂AXB^⊤}{X}= B⊗A$ respectively. The former is the case if you define $(A⊗B)_{ij, kl} = A_{ik}B_{jl}$, since then $AXB^⊤ = ∑_{kl} A_{ik}B_{jl} X_{kl} ≕ (A⊗B)⋅X$, is a tensor-contraction.